# DACPAC fails to deploy due to missing object

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, dacpac

I have a DACPAC for a complex database that I am trying to deploy via Powershell from an Azure DevOps Pipeline.

I am running it via Sqlpackage.exe

```
& $(sqlPackage) "/Action:Publish" "/TargetServerName:$(myserver)" /TargetDatabaseName:"(myDB)" "/p:CreateNewDatabase=True" "/TargetUser:$(myUser)" "/TargetPassword:$(myPass)"  "/SourceFile:$(myDacpac)" "/p:IgnoreUserSettingsObjects=True" "/p:IgnoreAuthorizer=True" "/p:VerifyDeployment=True" "/p:ExcludeObjectTypes=Logins;Aggregates" "/p:IncludeTransactionalScripts=True"
```

Looking at my log files I see that my [missingobject] is being created:

```
2021-11-04T17:52:30.6001273Z Creating [missingobject]...
```

Then many many steps later I get this error:

```
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 208, Level 16, State 103, Procedure MY_VIEW, Line 20 Invalid object name 'myschema.[missingobject]'.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
CREATE VIEW myschema.MY_VIEW
```

The missing object is an aggregate function defined in a CLR assembly of the same name. I can see that the CLR assembly exists in the Assemblies folder for the database. But the actual aggregate function does not exist.

It seems the dacpac is deploying the assembly, then the view. But the function should come before the view.

Looking online I see that sql server "intelligently" determines dependencies and deploys in the right order but that doesn't seem to be happening here.

Answer (score 0):

SQLPROJ and the dacpac must contain both: the assembly *and* the CREATE AGGREGATE/FUNCTION script.

> CLR assembly of the same name

Which means the only `Creating [missingobject]` stands for the assembly.

And your sqlpackage parameter `/p:ExcludeObjectTypes=Logins;Aggregates` leaves no chance for any aggregates. Remove `Aggregates` from it.